# Where should I put gem that I cannot download from rubyforge?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use cloudmade gem  but it is not stored in rubyforge so I have to download the .gem and to gem install cloudmade.gem.

Questions:
1)Is it wise to commit this to git repo so that others can use it as well?
  1a) If yes, where should I put the gem in my rails app?
  1b) If not, how should I share this with other people so that they won't have error when they do 'bundle install'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way IMHO :

clone the repo in Github,
in your Gemfile, add the path to your git depo using something like :

```
gem "abc", :git => "https://github.com........"
```

So that your team will be able to work on the project.

Try to contact the author of the gem to know if you can be the new maintainer of the gem.

Then upload it on Rubygems if you want.

Comment: thing is.... its not even on github. i have to download the .gem and do gem install cloudmade.gem. is it still possible to do this with :git => ??